# What happened to HL7 proxy statistics in WSO2 ESB 4.8.1?

Tags: wso2-esb

In WSO2 ESB 4.7.0, Request Count would always increment for my auto-acknowledging HL7 proxy services every time a new message came in. After upgrading to 4.8.1, Request Count is always 0. I have verified through my downstream dependencies that messages are indeed coming through.

What happened to proxy level statistics in 4.8.1, and what do I need to do to re-enable them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pointing out this bug - there seem to be some changes in the carbon statistics modules between 4.1.0 and 4.2.0. I've created a JIRA to track the issue at https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-2995